# Sequelize include even if it's null

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Sequelize express with Node.js as the backend, some data from my sequelize I need to include to another table but some of these data is null so the whole result I’m getting is null.

**Question:** how can I return some data if data it's available and return the other null if not data is there

```
router.get("/scheduled/:id", function(req, res, next) {

    models.Order.findOne({

        where: {
            id: req.params.id
        },
        attributes: ['orderStatus', 'id', 'serviceId', 'orderDescription', 'orderScheduledDate'],
        include: [{
            model: models.User,
            attributes: ['firstName', 'phoneNumber']
        }]
    }).then(function(data) {

        res.status(200).send({
            data: data,
            serviceName: data["serviceId"]
        });

    });

});
```

**I want:** the result should return null if there is no user for the order and return order details and user when it is null.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> However, a `where` clause on a related model will create an `inner join` and return only the instances that have matching sub-models. To return all parent instances, you should add `required: false` for more detail check [nested-eager-loading](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-usage/#nested-eager-loading)

```
var users  = require('./database/models').user;

    models.Order.findOne({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id
    },attributes: ['orderStatus','id','serviceId','orderDescription','orderScheduledDate'],
    include: [
        {model: users,required: false,
        attributes: ['firstName','phoneNumber']
        }
    ]
}).then(function(data) {

    res.status(200).send({data : data,serviceName : data["serviceId"]});

});
```

Comment: many thnx bro , i just removed the where and now i can return the parent data , it's already relation so no need to do where.

Comment: My code was working perfectly fine yesterday until today my queries started returning the equivalent of `users: null` in the Sequelize instance when I hadn't changed _anything_. I set `required` and it started working again. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can add attribute `required: false,`

```
 const result = await company.findAndCountAll({
        where: conditions,
        distinct: true,
        include: [
          media,
          {
            model: tag,
            where: tagCond,
          },
          { model: users, where: userCond, attributes: ['id'] },
          {
            model: category_company,
            as: 'categoryCompany',
            where: categoryCond,
          },
          { model: media, as: 'logoInfo' },
          { model: city, as: 'city' },
          {
            model: employee,
            as: 'employees',
            required: false,
            include: [{
              model: media,
              as: 'avatarInfo',
            }],
            where: {
              publish: {
                [Op.ne]: -1,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']],
        ...paginate({ currentPage: page, pageSize: limit }),
      });
```